# Client HTML Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am designing a website for a class I am taking currently. This class requires JavaScript to validate a form client-side. It has no pre-requisites other than it must use JavaScript to validate a form.

I've tried various attempts at code, scripting and adjusting my HTML as well and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. The underlying issue is that I know nothing about JavaScript, and a little about HTML/CSS.

Here is my Form in HTML (and CSS formatting). It's a simple form with a name, email address and a comment box. The website doesn't need to be actually functioning, so there is no server side processing hooked up or anything. Just simple validation.

HTML

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="demo_form.asp"
action="http://webdevfoundations.net/scripts/formdemo.asp" >

    <div class="myRow">

    <p style="color: #cc6600; padding-left: 50px;"><b>Get Our Newsletter!</b></p>
    <label style="color: #cc6600;" class="labelCol" for="myName"><b>Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" />

    </div>

    <div class="myRow">
      <label style="color: #cc6600;" class="labelCol" for="myEmail"><b>E-mail:</b>  
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" />
    </div>

   <div>
     <label style="color: #cc6600;" class="labelCol" for="myComments"><b>Comments:</b>
     </label>
     <textarea name="myComments" id="myComments" rows="1" cols="30">
     </textarea>
  </div>

   <div class="mySubmit">
      <input type="submit" value="Get Newsletter" />
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS I use to format it

```
 #myForm 
     { color: #ffffff; 
       font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;   
       width: auto;
       padding: 15px;
       min-width: 400px;
     }

   .myRow 
     { padding-bottom: 20px;
     }

   .mySubmit 
     { margin-top: 10px;
       margin-left: 110px;
     }
   .labelCol 
     { float: left;
       width: 100px;
       text-align: right;
       padding-right: 10px;
     }
```

I'm not sure how to add the script portion to simply validate: a name was entered and the email address has a "@" and a "." as a valid email address. Here is sample code presented to me, but I have no idea how to implement it:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Sorry if this is a mess, and if my HTML is a disaster. First time ever making a website!

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) is for sure not the place to learn about this. Just search SO for examples there are 100s or 1000s

Comment: This question is pretty broad in scope, it needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to use `javascript` for client side validation now. `HTML5` have built in attributes and types for client side validations.

for example, For checking `@` and `.` in email address, you can use `<input type=email>`.

If you want to check for blank field, you can use required attribute as:

```
<input type="email" required>
```

For more input types in `HTML5`,Read a [classic article on HTML doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/).

[One more article on HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/)

However, If you want client side validation using only javascript, the This article on [client side validation using JS and DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)  will be useful.

**Example of client side email validation using JS:**

Take a text input in html and a button input like this :

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='txtEmail'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' onclick='Javascript:checkEmail();'/>
</form>
```

Now when the button is clicked then the JavaScript function `Submit()` will be called. Now write the below code in `head` section.

```
 <script language="javascript">

    function checkEmail() {

        var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        return false;
     }

}</script>
```

`/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/` is a regex pattern for email address...It is very difficult to explain this here...[Please see this link for more information](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

In the function, the `test()` method in `filter.test(email.value)` checks for pattern match.and if condition returns boolean value(true or false) for accordingly matching/not matching pair.

Comment: However using JS is a requisite

Comment: I appreciate the input! I saved the link you provided. For future reference I would love to use HTML5 only, that would be idea. Unfortunately for this website I am required to use javascript.

Comment: @user3847046 wait ..I'm editing for more...